# Reactive Form validation not working

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have created a component for user signup

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {UserManagementService} from '../user-management.service';
import {User} from "../user";
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup,Validators} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signup-component',
  templateUrl: './signup-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signup-component.component.css'],
  providers:[UserManagementService]
})
export class SignupComponentComponent  {

  newUser:User;

  signupForm:FormGroup; 

  constructor(private userManagementService: UserManagementService, private fb:FormBuilder) {
    this.createForm();
  }

  createForm(){
    this.signupForm = this.fb.group({
      firstName:['',Validators.required], 
      lastName:['',Validators.required],
      email:['',Validators.required],
      password:['',Validators.required]
    });
  }

  addUser(){
    this.newUser = new User({
      firstname:this.signupForm.get('firstName').value,
      lastname:this.signupForm.get('lastName').value,
      email:this.signupForm.get('email').value
    });
    console.log("in SignupComponentComponent: addUser: "+this.newUser);
    this.userManagementService.addUser(this.newUser);
  }

}
```

Following is the template

```
<div class="div__signup"> 
  <div class="content_div--white"> 

    <form class="signup-form" [formGroup]="signupForm" (ngSubmit)="addUser()" novalidate>
      <label for="firstname" class="first-name">First Name</label>

      <input id="firstname" type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="firstName" required>

      <label for="lastname" class="last-name">Last Name</label>
      <input id="lastname" type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="lastName" required>

      <label for="email" class="email"> Email</label>
      <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" formControlName="email" required>

      <label for="password" class="password">Password</label>
      <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" formControlName="password" required>

      <label for="verify-password" class="verify-password">Verify Password</label>
      <input id="verify-password" type="password" class="form-control" required>

      <button type="submit"  id="signup-button" class="content-div__button--blue"> Sign Up! </button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

UserManagementService is

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {User} from './user';

@Injectable()
export class UserManagementService {

  constructor() { }

  addUser(user:User){
    console.log("In UserManagementService: addUser: "+user)
  }

}
```

Even if I submit the form withtou any data (all `input` empty), I see the following two console messages

```
in SignupComponentComponent: addUser: [object Object]
In UserManagementService: addUser: [object Object]
```

It seems the `Validators` are not working (I must not be using them correctly). Why does the `UserManagementService` gets called. Shouldn't Angular not submit the form if there are errors in the form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go :

```
  addUser(){
    if (this.signupForm.valid) {
      this.newUser =  this.signupForm.value;
      console.log("in SignupComponentComponent: addUser: ", this.newUser);
      this.userManagementService.addUser(this.newUser);
    }
  }

  <button type="submit" [disabled]="signupForm.invalid" id="signup-button" class="content-div__button--blue"> Sign Up! </button>
```

You first need to test if the form is valid. Angular lets you submit the form even if it's invalid, so that you can make something of your own (for instance, display an error message).

You also can shorten your code by getting the value of the form directly, instead of re-creating the user like you did.

You can also deactivate your button if your form is invalid, so that the user can't send the form.

Comment: By the way, when you want to display objects in your console, use a comma instead of a plus sign. This will make your object expandable so that you can see its properties, instead of displaying `[Object object]`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have never use that comma before. Could you please show an example?

Comment: An example of the comma ? Just use my piece of code, I made a console log with it :)

Comment: ah! didnt notice that. Thanks